# Calculate expected value of CDF of a different Beta variable

Tags: distributions, expected-value, cumulative-distribution-function, beta-distribution

Let 
$$
  X_1 \sim Beta(\alpha_1,\beta_1) \\
  X_2 \sim Beta(\alpha_2,\beta_2).
$$
Let $F_X(x) = P( X \le x )$ be the CDF of $X$ and $\mathbb{E}_{X}(\cdot)$ be expectation with respect to $X$.
How to calculate
$$
\mathbb{E}_{X_1}(F_{X_2}(X_1)) = ?
$$

Comment: This can be solved with a computer algebra system as: $$\frac{\Gamma \left(\alpha _1+\alpha _2\right) \Gamma \left(\alpha _1+\beta _1\right) \Gamma \left(\alpha _2+\beta _2\right)}{\Gamma \left(\alpha _1\right) \Gamma \left(\beta _2\right)} \, _3\tilde{F}_2\left(\alpha _2,\alpha _1+\alpha _2,1-\beta _2;\alpha _2+1,\alpha _1+\alpha _2+\beta _1;1\right)$$ ... the latter denoting a regularized generalized hypergeometric function

Comment: Yes. The problem can be viewed as the probability of event $\{X_2 \leq X_1\}$ and can be reduced to the finding PDF 

of ration of beta random variables and then use the results from paper: Pham-Gia, T. (2000). Distributions of the ratios of independent beta variables and applications. Communications in Statistics - Theory and Methods, 29(12), 2693–2715. http://doi.org/10.1080/03610920008832632 

to get the above expression.

But is it possible to get a solution which does not involve hypergeometric functions?

Comment: If the two distributions are the same, then the answer will be $\frac12$ (by the probability integral transform -- i.e. that the cdf of a distribution has a standard Uniform distribution). Absent that, the answer is not generally a half and requires the hyper solution.

Comment: It should be possible to avoid the hyper solution provided one among $\alpha_1$,$\beta_1$,$\alpha_2$,$\beta_2$ is a positive integer. For instance, if $\beta_2$ is a positive integer, expand $(1-x)^{\beta_2-1}$ using the binomial theorem, and solve the integral by regular means. The result is a finite sum involving beta functions. I can spell it out if you wish.